# printer pending, print report , and Random printer issues

Tags: printing, ubuntu-mate

So im trying to print on multiple printers. Sometimes they work, sometimes they dont. it seems random.
Currently im using an epson p8570 and yesterday it worked fine, today, in the print que it says pending print report.

Im usually using it over wifi because usb connection is functional even less. but today USB printing is working. Im confused as all hell.

Comment: appologies, im using ubuntu mate 22.04. Im not too sure what im doing as far as log checking. ive checked a few based on writeups ive seen but im not sure what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.